# $f(x)$ is monotonically increasing function for all real $x$, $f’’(x)>0$ and $f^{-1}$ exists, then prove that [CONT]...

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, monotone-functions

> $f(x)$ is monotonically increasing function for all real $x$, $f’’(x)>0$ and $f^{-1}$ exists, then prove that $\frac{f^{-1}(x_1)+f^{-1}(x_2)}{2}<f^{-1}(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2})$

The conclusions that can be drawn from the given data is that $f(x)$ is monotonous and increasing, so $f^{-1}$ is also monotonous and increasing. Also $f(x)$ is concaved upwards, so $f^{-1} (x)$ is concaved downwards. How do I solve from here?

Comment: Just apply the definition of concave downward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visualisation helps.$g(x)=f^{-1}(x)$.

Imgine $g(x)$ concave downward.Let P be the point $(x_1,g(x_1))$ and Q be $(x_2,g(x_2))$.

Thus the point $(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2},\frac{g(x_1)+g(x_2)}{2})$ is  the mid point of of segment $PQ$.

Also a perpendicular line  line drawn from $(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2},0)$ meets the curve in $(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2},g(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}))$.

It is easy to see that this point lies above midpoint of $PQ$

Comment: Why does $\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$ correspond to $(\frac{g(x_1)+g(x_2)}{2}$

Comment: @Aditya! but i never said that i only said it corresponds to $g(\frac{(x_1+x_2}{2})$

Comment: @Aditya i heve edited to make it more clear

Comment: Wait, so is $g$ not a function, since two values of $g$ correspond to a single $x$

Comment: @Aditya i think you have misunderstood , when i meant midpoint of PQ ,it does not mean that point lies on the graph.Try drawing a diagram ,it becomes clear.

Comment: @Aditya see the picture given in link ,( the concave part) https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter6/6_2_5_jensen%27s_inequality.php

Comment: Yeah so in the first line you wrote $\frac{g(x_1)+g(x_2)}{2}$ while in the next it be became $g(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$ for the same midpoint of PQ, that is the part I don’t understand

Comment: @Aditya $g(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2})$ is not the midpoint of  segment PQ.it is the point **on the graph** corresponding to the x coordinate $\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$  Have you tried drawing a diagram?

Comment: I have drawn the graph. I understand that $\frac{g(x_1)+g(x_2)}{2}$ is the midpoint of *segment* PQ whose x coordinate corresponds to $\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$. Similarly, $g(\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$ is the point on the curve that intersects the curve at that very point. What I don’t understand is how can two y coordinates exist for the same $\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}$

Comment: @Aditya one point lies on the graph and the other doesn't , so there is no problem.For eg (1,2)(1,3)  there are 2 y coordinates for the same point on x coordinate

Comment: Oh okay, I get it now. Thanks!

Comment: @Aditya you are welcome